# Process Instance Step Comments Character limit?

Tags: community

Hi I have approval process and I want to capture the comments into custom text field. What is the size of Approval Process comments box in characters so that I can choose the correct text field. What will be the best text field to capture those comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in workbench, the character limitation is 4000. 
It is not Rich, so my suggestion is a Long Text Area

[image: workbench shot]